# Why can't my post-receive hook run a virtualenv source command?

Tags: python, linux, git, virtualenv, git-post-receive

I have a post-receive hook that is running as user 'git'. I have a virtualenv /python/ve//bin/activate that is readable by git. Running:

```
source /python/ve/<name>/bin/activate
```

works fine for a user in the git group.

When it runs as a post-receive hook after a push, I get the error "source: not found".

I'm not sure where else to look - any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is something of a guess, since you haven't quoted your complete `post-receive` hook, but I suspect that you don't have a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) pointing to `/bin/bash` at the top.  Your `post-receive` hook should begin:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I suspect this because if I run a strict Bourne shell, like `dash`, I get the same error when trying to source anything with `source`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I had accidentally had /bin/sh as I'd copied it from another person's hook. I'd just changed the shell for the git user, but forgot about the shebang line. Thank you for such a quick accurate answer.

Comment: No problem - it's very easy to do :)